# The edges connecting my vertices are loopy rather that straight. Is it possible do straighten them + if so how can this be done?

Tags: edges

I am unable to change the loopy form of the edges and as a result cannot get sharp curves. Also, I believe the problem may have arose after creasing the edges, but am not 100% sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the modifier panel, disable "Adjust to cage" in order to modify the actual vertices position.

[image]